# How to show laravel api error in digitalocean?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I deploy my Laravel + vue project on the Digitalocean apps and some of my api are working but some are not.
When I look into the api response I received `message: "Server Error"`,
But the api is working on localhost and gives error after the deployment.

Is there a way to view the actual error message of the api reponse? so that I can easily understand what causing the error and fix it.

But I really find it weird that it causing error in the digitalocean apps, but works on my local machine.

I've tried searching for hours how to view the errors but I can't find it.
please help me. Thank you!

Comment: You can find all errors in storage/logs/laravel.log (if its a laravel error, and not a server error). if you use the laravel debugbar, you can open all visited urls in the bar by clicking the folder icon

Comment: where can view that sir in digital ocean? my app is running directly from my github repo

Comment: Follow DO guideline on troubleshoot your App. Also make sure you've enabled debug mode. [https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/troubleshoot-app/](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/how-to/troubleshoot-app/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log in to your server and look in the file  storage/logs/laravel.log.

Otherwise, I would suggest using a service such as Bugsnag or Sentry, which have integrations with laravel and will give you a dashboard with all your errors

Some people suggest putting APP_DEBUG to true, but that is a security risk as your customers will be able to see the error as well, and you should **never** do this on a production server

Comment: I agree on the APP_DEBUG part, but never? We sometimes deploy to a production server, with a folder password, to test the installation. in that case its not really a problem.